# List<List<string>> values to into string[][] array C#

Tags: c#, string, list, multidimensional-array

I have the a following two variables:

```
        List<List<string>> result
        string[][] resultarray
```

I want to take the values from result and read store them in resultarray like so: 
[["one", "two"], ["three"], ["four", "five", six"], ["seven"], ["eight"]] etc.

I have the following code:

```
        string[][] resultarray = new string[resultint][];
        int a = new int();
        int b = new int();
        foreach (List<string> list in result)
        {
            foreach (string s in list)
            {
                resultarray[b][a] = s;
                a++;
            }
            b++;
        }
        return resultarray;
```

However, when debugging, I get a "NullExceptionError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to increment a or b. I've also tried declaring them as:

```
    int a = 0
    int b = 0
```

...This doesn't work either. Am I not declaring these correctly or does it have to do with the foreach loop?

Comment: second foreach is unnecessary, just use `resultarray[b] = list.ToArray();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each sub-array starts as `null` - you need to **create** the inner arrays.

But a simpler approach is:

```
var resultarray = result.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

which gives the stated outcome if we assume the input is something like:

```
var result = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> { "one", "two" },
    new List<string> { "three" },
    new List<string> { "four", "five", "six" },
    new List<string> { "seven" },
    new List<string> { "eight" },
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to wrap my head around LINQ but I still don't quite understand it. I'll do some more reading.

Comment: @reallybadatmath basically what it says is "create a projection, where each item becomes the result of `ToArray()` on that item; and then create an array from the results of that projection"

Comment: Thankyou again Marc. Your explanation makes sense -- a LOT simpler than trying to target the indexes with incrementing integers.

Answer (score 3):

Before the inner loop:

```
resultarray[b] = new string[list.Count];
```

Comment: If we were going to anything with the inner loop, @sasjaq has the truth of it